# How to show that the local homology at a point on the boundary of the half-plane is zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\mathbb{H}^n = \{x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n \geq 0 \}$. i.e. the half plane. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \{0\}$ be a point on the boundary.

How do I show that $H_q(\mathbb{H}^n \mid y) = 0$ for all $q$?

**Attempt**: we have a long exact sequence,

$$\cdots \to H_q(\mathbb{H}^n - y) \to H_q(\mathbb{H}^n) \to H_q(\mathbb{H}^n \mid y) \to H_{q-1}(\mathbb{H}^n -y) \to H_{q-1}(\mathbb{H}^n) \to \cdots.$$

Now, $H_q(\mathbb{H}^n) = 0$ for all $q$ since the half plane, like all of $\mathbb{R^n}$, is contractible. So, $H_q(\mathbb{H}^n \mid y) \cong H_{q-1}(\mathbb{H}^n - y)$.

However, $H_{q-1}(\mathbb{H}^n - y) = 0$ for all $q$ since $\mathbb{H}^n - y$ is also contractible?

Comment: $\mathbb H^n -y$: what about loops about the missing point?

Comment: There are no loops around the missing point: It's on the boundary.

Comment: Yes the half space with a point on the boundary removed is still contractible - just project every point to $y+(0,0,\ldots,0,0,1)$ along a line segment.